# MYSQL : an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select t.name 
from (pratip_Person natural join pratip_M_Director) as t;
```

What is the syntax error in this query?

Comment: I googled a lot but could not come to a satisfiable solution .

Comment: Where's the join condition? Parentheses aren't needed. You can alias specific tables not the join statement.

Comment: In my opinion `natural join` should be avoided because it is susceptible to side effects.  Personally I would always use the more explicit `join on`

Answer (score 1):

The brackets around `(pratip_Person natural join pratip_M_Director)` are your problem!

Try

```
select t.name from pratip_Person natural join pratip_M_Director as t;
```

(unless the Q at the start is really part of your query!)

Comment: why is that a problem ? If we dont put he brackets then how can we identify whether t represents pratip_M_Director or the natural join ?

Comment: I am not really sure how `t` could represent the natural join as opposed to either the `pratip_M_Director` table or the entire `select` statement... but the brackets being where they are now is causing the syntax error.

Comment: @jaig You alias *tables*, not join *operations*. A field can come either from Person or Director. If you have a column named `Name` in both, you need to specify whether you want the Person's or the Director's Name. Are you confusing the join with a subquery?

Comment: The closing parenthesis is in the wrong place. Also, the parentheses are completely redundant. But the parentheses in and of themselves aren't 'the problem'; just their positioning.